# Access component scope reactive variable from parent in Svelte not updating

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component

I have a `TableRow.svelte` component with a on click event that toggles a collapse class and changes the calling element text.  The callback property works but the text never changes.

```
<script>
    export let rowData = {};
    export let labels = {};
    export let id = -1
    export let toggleCollapsible = function(){}
    let isCollapsed = true;
    $: isCollapsed
</script>
<tr>
    <td>{rowData.season}</td>
    <td>{rowData.farm}</td>
    <td>{rowData.block}</td>
    <td>{rowData.date}</td>
    <td>{rowData.totals}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <span data-row="{id}" role="button" on:click={toggleCollapsible}>{labels.realised} [{#if isCollapsed}<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>{:else}<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>{/if}]</span>
    </td>
    <td>{rowData.realised_date ?? "--"}</td>
    <td>{rowData.realised_total ?? "--"}</td>
</tr>
```

In the `App.svelte` component the `TableRow` component is initialised as follows:

```
<script>
    import FormRow from './FormRow.svelte';
    import TableRow from './TableRow.svelte';
    
    let table = [
        {id:1,block:"X",farm"xY",season:2023,total:3400, date:"2023-01-23"}
     ];
    let isCollapsed;
    let loading = true;
    let colspan = 4;
    let labels = {
        block: "Block",
        date: "Date",
        season: "Season",
        realised: "Realised",
        no_data: "No data",
        farm: "Farm"
    }
    $: loading;
    const loaded = () => {
        loading = false;
        return "";
    };

    function toggleCollapsible(e) {
        const id = e.target.dataset.row;
        if(id>0) {
            const tr = document.getElementById("row_form_"+id);
            tr.classList.toggle("show");
            isCollapsed = !tr.classList.contains("show");  // this does not update component scope reactive value
        }
    }

    function onSubmit(e) {
        // do submit things
    }
</script>
<style>
    :global(.opaque) {
        pointer-events: none!important;
        opacity: 0.6!important;
        transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out!important;
    }
</style>
    <FormRow onSubmit={onSubmit}/>

    <div class="container-full p-2">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-12 w-100">
                <table class="mobile-table mobile-table-bordered text-center w-100">
                    <thead>
                        <tr style="background-color: #81d5c0; color: rgb(63, 63, 63);">
                            <th>{labels.season}</th>
                            <th>{labels.farm}</th>
                            <th>{labels.block}</th>
                            <th>{labels.date}</th>
                            <th>{labels.total}</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {#if table!==null && table!==undefined && table.length>0}
                        {loaded()}
                            {#each table as t, idx (t.id)}
                                <TableRow id={t.id} labels={labels} toggleCollapsible={toggleCollapsible} rowData={t}/>
                                <tr id="row_form_{t.id}" class="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <td colspan="{colspan}">
                                        <FormRow onSubmit={onSubmit}/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            {/each}
                        {:else}
                        {loaded()}
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="{colspan}">{labels.no_data}</td>
                            </tr>
                        {/if}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How do I make the component variable reactive from parent scope function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to not pass `toggleCollapsible` and handle the `isCollapsed` change inside `TableRow` component with a second `on:click` handler

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <span data-row="{id}"
                    role="button"
                    on:click
                    on:click={() => isCollapsed = !isCollapsed}
            >
            {labels.realised}
            ...
        </span>
    </td>
  ...
</tr>
```

and handle the `on:click` without handler on the component element like this

```
<TableRow ... on:click={toggleCollapsible} />
```

Notice that if a variable has no dependency but is just a value like

```
let isCollapsed = true;
```

it's reactive per se and adding `$: isCollapsed` is redundant

If there's no reason against modifiying the `table` data, an alternative approach that avoids `toggleCollapsible` and the querying and classList toggle part inside it alltogether would be this

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/0a2dbe8e09e64972b19a51f35266e5b8?version=3.59.1)

Using `bind:prop` on the component - [tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/component-bindings)
and the `class:` directive - [tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/classes)

```
<script>
    import TableRow from './TableRow.svelte'
    let table = [
        {id:1,block:"X",farm:"xY",season:2023,total:3400, date:"2023-01-23"},
    ];
</script>

<table>
    {#each table as t, idx (t.id)}
    <TableRow rowData={t} bind:isCollapsed={t.isCollapsed}/>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class:show={!t.isCollapsed}>
                Show if not collapsed
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {/each}
</table>

<style>
    span {
        display: none;
    }
    .show {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

###### TableRow.svelte

```
<script>
    export let rowData = {}
    export let isCollapsed = true
</script>

<tr>
    <td>
        <button on:click={() => isCollapsed = !isCollapsed}>
            toggle
        </button>
        row: {rowData.id} isCollapsed: {isCollapsed}
    </td>
</tr>
```

While there are ways to solve this, I wonder if it wasn't better to not have the `<tr>` element after `<TableRow>` seperate, but everything inside one component...

Comment: The redesign solved the issue. Thanks.  It means working only with component scope properties and no reason to expose anything to the parent.

Answer (score 1):

There is no connection between those variables at all, they are *not* in the same scope.

If you want to pass the state into the component, `isCollapsed` should be a property of `TableRow`. If you want to get state out again, use [`bind:...`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-bind-property).

Also, you should *not* manipulate DOM manually like adding/removing classes; the whole point of Svelte is to not have to do any of that. For classes there is a [`class:...` directive](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-class-name), the `TableRow` should manage that internally and just expose what can be changed via properties.

Passing functions around is not a great idea either. One should generally just use properties and events. If you need to react to some interaction happening within `TableRow`, [dispatch an event](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-createeventdispatcher) and listen to that.

`$: isCollapsed` does absolutely nothing, [see docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-3-$-marks-a-statement-as-reactive).

Comment: Good and simple idea.  The event dispatcher is the simpler solution but I can not find a way to scope the class directive to a specific element id.  I therefore went with a suggested redesign.